# DoInit in LWC. Making lifecycle hook (connectedCallback) as public using @api

Tags: lightning-web-components, public-reactive-properties

In LWC, I am trying to implement onload/doInit logic as in aura component. for a certain scenario I have to reinvoke/call that doInit method from the parent component.

Instead doInt,in LWC am achieving this using @api on connectedCallback method

*Child Component*

```
//child.js
@api 
connectedCallback(){ 
   // my do init logic
}
```

*Parent Component*

```
//parent.js
...
this.template.querySelector('c-child').connectedCallback();
...
```

**Is it good to make connectedCallback() public? Is there any other issue which will affect this modal? If not please give me a good modal for DoInit in LWC**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried making the connected callback public, but I have an alternative for this.
You can write a separate public method for init. Let us say,

```
@api
doInit(){
    // do your init logic.
}
```

You can call this method from `connectedcallback` like this.

```
connectedCallback(){ 
   this.doInit();
}
```

Also, you can call the same method from the parent,

```
//parent.js
...
this.template.querySelector('c-child').doInit();
...
```

Comment: dumbest question. 